# Launching activity from spinner crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I cannot find the problem anywhere, the first activity works without a hitch, and the second (and all the others) are almost copies of it, just with different values and calculations, so they SHOULD be working

My first activity starts like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
....
....
private final String[] generations = {"Gen2", "Gen3", "Gen4", "Gen5", "Gen6", "Gen7"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_Main);
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.genchoice);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, generations);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

The spinner code is

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case (1):
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, gen2.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Gen3.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, gen4.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            break;
        case 4:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, gen5.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            break;
        case 5:
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;
        case 6:
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(this, gen7.class);
            startActivity(intent7);
            break;
    }
}
```

and my secong activity starts like this

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class gen2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
....
.....
private final String[] generations = {"Gen2", "Gen3", "Gen4", "Gen5", "Gen6", "Gen7"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gen2);
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.genchoice);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, generations);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

errorlog

> 09-30 10:59:37.896 3646-3646/com.example.rune.shinycalculator
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.rune.shinycalculator, PID: 3646
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.rune.shinycalculator/com.example.rune.shinycalculator.gen2}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at com.example.rune.shinycalculator.gen2.onCreate(gen2.java:27)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> 09-30 10:59:39.823 3646-3646/com.example.rune.shinycalculator
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3646 SIG: 9

Comment: Please post the error log

Comment: Replace 'this' with 'MainActivity' and check if it will work.

Comment: tried to replace "this" with MainActivity, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the Naming Convention. Class name should be CamelCase(start with Cpas). 
 gen.class should be Gen.class

Go through below link

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

```
Use 

Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Gen2.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: true, and tried with one of the activities, makes no difference

Comment: it's not an anonymous class, the MainActivity directly implements OnItemSelectedListener, so it's one and the same class.

Comment: its working for me, so make sure
1. Your class name starts with Caps(Gen2) everywhere
2. You have declared your target class to manifest file

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside anonymous Class this refer to instances of that class . So Change "this" to "Mainactivity.this"

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, gen2.class);
```

Comment: doesn't make a difference, so that is not the (only) problem

Comment: Your error show that you are not inflating the spinner correctly. Make sure Id you inflating match with ID you set in xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the Spinner in the layouts for the other activities (gen3, ...) but are still trying to set a listener for it and that's why you get the NPE.

*=== Before stacktrace ===*

You probably haven't added the other activities in the AndroidManifest.xml, like this

```
<activity android:name=".gen3"/>
<activity android:name=".gen4"/>
```

Remember to set the correct package for the class in **android:name**.
Also be careful with the uppercase/lowercase in the class name because it's case sensitive.

Comment: correct package? can you explain? the manifest looks like this
        <activity android:name=".gen2">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Gen3">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".gen4">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".gen5">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".gen7" />

Comment: The classes must be in the same package(folder) as the application package (the one at the top of the manifest) if you only place a **.** before the class name. Otherwise you must prefix the class name with the rest of the path between the package base path and the package your class is located in: for example if your application package is **com.foo** but your activity is in the package **com.foo.bar** the android name in manifest should be **.bar.gen3** not **.gen3**

Comment: so they should all just be below eachother?
<activity
android:name="number one"
android name="number two"
etc.
</activity>
?

Comment: Apparently this isn't the problem, i did not know the stacktrace at that time. If you have all activities in the same package as MainActivity, you needn't worry about packages.